# GRUB not recognizing filesystem

Tags: filesystems, boot, grub, artix-linux

I'm a new to Linux, and I'm trying to boot the graphical installation of Artix Linux with the XFCE desktop environment off of the ISO `artix-xfce-openrc-20210726-x86_64.iso` onto my Lenovo Thinkpad T480s.

When I boot from the HDD USB that contains the ISO, I'm directed to a blank terminal except for a short welcome message for GRUB and the words

```
error: unknown filesystem
```

By the way, I formatted the USB with Rufus using FAT32. The Thinkpad that I recently purchased had no operating system(s) installed, and the hard drives in the terminal are listed as "`hd0`" and "`hd1`". Running the "`insmod normal`" command that I've seen could be a possible help doesn't work due to the unrecognized filesystem.

What is the best approach to go about fixing this? Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like something went wrong when creating the usb boot media. How did you get the iso on the usb stick? If this is an installer iso/image, you should write it raw into the media. You could use etcher to do this. (No need to format as it'll be entirely overwritten anyways). https://www.balena.io/etcher/

Comment: @rudib I fixed the problem by using Etcher. I dunno why that worked instead of Rufus, but we're running alright now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I never really used Rufus, so I can't say for sure, but AFAIK: Rufus does too much in your case. You're downloading a disk image that includes raw data (as in partition, bootloader, etc). AFAIK, Rufus will partition the disk, install a bootloader and put the iso somewhere. So what might have happened is that Rufus put the iso inside a partition while it was meant to be written directly.

Comment: "etcher" / "Etcher" = [balenaEtcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etcher_(software))